# Running a crontab every 15 minutes not working on linux redhat

Tags: linux, shell, unix, cron, redhat

I want to run a crontab every 15minutes. I tried this:

```
0 */15 * * * ./usr/My_PATH/run.sh
```

But I get this error:

```
0 command not found
```

Is there something wrong with the syntax ?

Many thanks.

UPDATE:

I corrected the script and I tried this:

```
*/15 * * * * /My_Path/run.sh
```

and this

```
0,15,30,45 * * * * /My_Path/run.sh
```

In both cases I get an error.

```
#1 bash: */15: No such file or directory
#2 bash: 0,15,30,45 command not found
```

Comment: is that the correct path for your script? does that script have a correct #! shebang?

Comment: yes when I run ./run.sh it works.

Comment: `./usr` means "in the home directory of the user account this job runs at", so unless your script is `/home/tantaoui/usr/My_Path/run.sh`, ...

Comment: On top of the path problem, this is "every 15 hours", not minutes. And the message "0: command not found" make it look like this line is executed.  Use `crontab -e` to modify your crontab. A crontab is not a script, don't execute it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this:

```
0 */15 * * * ./usr/My_PATH/run.sh
```

fails with this error:

```
0 command not found
```

then you're trying to run it as a shell command. You need to feed it to the `crontab` command. There are several ways to do this.

`crontab -l` will list the current contents of your crontab; it doesn't modify it.

`crontab -e` will open (a copy of) your crontab in a text editor and let you modify it. This is probably the simplest way to update it.

`crontab filename` reads the specified file and *replaces* your current crontab with its contents. (If you already have a crontab, this will quietly clobber it.)

The method I recommend is to keep a separate file containing your crontab (say, `crontab.txt`).

First, if you already have a non-empty crontab (check with `crontab -l`), save it to the file:

```
crontab -l > crontab.txt
```

Make whatever additions or other changes you want *to that file*, and then use

```
crontab crontab.txt
```

to install the updated crontab.

You can keep backup copies (I maintain mine in a source control system) so you can recover if you mess something up. And you can do a quick `crontab -e` if you want to test something, then re-run `crontab crontab.txt` to revert to the stored crontab.

---

The syntax of the crontab line in your question:

```
0 */15 * * * ./usr/My_PATH/run.sh
```

is correct, but the path `./usr/My_PATH/run.sh` looks like it may be incorrect. Cron jobs run from your home directory, so the path is valid only if the `usr` directory is directly under your home directory (and in that case the `./` is unnecessary). It's probably better to specify the full path, which can start with `$HOME/`.

Comment: Won't `crontab crontab.txt` clobber whateve ris there? I'd suggest it might be worth making clearer that that's the case.

Comment: @Sobrique: Yes. I did mention that, but I agree it should be clearer. I'll edit the question soon.

Comment: @Sobrique: How does that look?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

First field is minutes. Second field is hours. You're setting it off at zero minutes past the hour, every 15th hour. So basically - 15:00 each day.

You want:

```
*/15 * * * * /some_script
```

Furthermore - `./` - it's a relative path, and that's probably a bad idea with cron, because it doesn't `chdir` to run stuff. Use an absolute path to avoid confusion. If you absolutely need to be in a particular directory for the script to work, you can try:

```
cd /path/to/script && ./this_script
```

So it's quite possible that you've got broken permissions or just not finding a relative path that you're using.

Comment: I tried with `*/15 * * * * /My_PATH/run.sh` and I get `bash: */15: No such file or directory`.